# Map and render axios response data in an external JS file

Tags: javascript, axios

I have two files, one is axios.js (basically for the fetching), and the other is to get the results and render content depending on data.

I've tried different stuff but I can't get it to work.

The JSON is correct. I want to render an availability text based on the value attributes of `#name` and `#price`, it has to match.

I have logged before the values and it's correct, but when I try to render based on the API, this is when I'm lost.

This is what the files look like:

#### axios.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const test1 = () => { 
  return axios.get('data/models.json')
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
}
```

#### example.js

```js
import { test1 } from "./axios";
let fetchModels = test1();
const price = document.querySelector('#price');
const name = document.querySelector('#name');

test1.then((result) => {
  const i, j, match;
  match = false;
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < result[i].prices.length; j++) {
        if (result[i].prices[j].final == price.value &&
            result[i].name == name.value {
              match = true;
              return document.querySelector('#availability').textContent = result[i].prices[j].availability;  
        }
      }
  }
  if (match == false) {
    console.log('No match found.');
  }
})
```

Of course, I'm getting the `No match found` log when executing it.

Answer (score 1):

Write it insidea function instead of calling it directly, in this case, you want to create a function that calls test1() inside of it, this will return a promise, then you just can deal with the resolved and error parts of that promise as normal, in then() you will return the data and in the catch() you will log whatever error handler you want.

Comment: It is actually in a function, just wanted to paste less code.

But I fixed it, one of the values was different from a result string.